# Software to draw signals, time-diagrams, etc for electronics?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I am looking a tool to draw signal, time diagram etc. Are there any software wcih is available in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Signal can be various :

- triangle
- square
- etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically designed for developing electronic circuits we may have a look at the collection of tools from the [**gEDA**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/geda) [image: Install geda] collection of tools:

> Currently, the gEDA project offers a mature suite of free software applications for electronics design, including schematic capture, attribute management, bill of materials (BOM) generation, netlisting into over 20 netlist formats, analog and digital simulation, and printed circuit board (PCB) layout.<sup>from release notes</sup>

See also the [gEDA project homepage](http://www.geda-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try LibreCad.

> LibreCAD is an application for computer aided design (CAD) in two
>   dimensions (2D). With LibreCAD you can create technical drawings such
>   as plans for buildings, interiors, mechanical parts or schematics and
>   diagrams. <sup>1</sup>

It can be downloaded from USC

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/librecad/)</sup>